# Replace line x from a file with line x from another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two files like below:

```
file1:
a b c
1 2 3
a y z

file2:
A B C
0 0 0
A Y Z
```

I want to replace line 1 in file1 with line 1 from file2, line 3 from file1 with line 3 from file2 or any other line with the equivalent line from the other file, based on a pattern. (The two files always have the same number of lines and I always know that line x from one file will replace line x in the other one).

I tried this:

```
while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == "A"* ]]; then
        VAR=$line
        while read -r line; do
            if [[ $line == "a"* ]];then
                sed -i "s/$line/$VAR/g" file1.txt
            fi
        done < file1.txt
    fi
done < file2.txt
```

The output is:

```
A B C
1 2 3
A B C
```

The DESIRED output should be:

```
A B C
1 2 3
A Y Z
```

This does not work because VAR does not change until the nested while loop ends.
Can someone provide a simpler solution to this?

Thanks!

Comment: *any other line with the equivalent line from the other file, based on a pattern.* What is the pattern that you are looking for

Comment: At the moment it's unclear what you're asking - please [edit] your question to make it clear which lines should be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the condition for replacement is that a line in `file1` begins with `a`, as your attempt seems to suggest:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { line[NR] = $0; next } /^a/ { $0 = line[FNR] } 1' file2 file1
```

For other conditions, simply replace `/^a/` with a condition that identifies the lines to be replaced.

This works by first reading the lines of `file2` into an array and swapping them in while processing `file1` when the condition holds. In detail:

```
NR == FNR {       # if the number of the current record is the same as the
                  # number of the current record in the current file -- that
                  # is: while processing the first file (file2)
  line[NR] = $0   # remember the line by that number
  next            # do nothing else
}
                  # afterwards (while processing the second file (file1)):
/^a/ {            # if the current record begins with a
  $0 = line[FNR]  # swap in the corresponding remembered line
}
1                 # print
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex so that it matches on lower case "a". You also need to add the tilda "~" within the if statement to get it to do a regex. This needs to be done for both if statements - try:

```
while read -r line; do
if [[ $line =~ ([aA]*) ]]; then
    VAR=$line
    while read -r line; do
        if [[ $line =~ ([aA]*) ]];then
            sed -i "s/$line/$VAR/g" file1.txt
        fi
    done < file1.txt
fi
done < file2.txt
```